# How to search for directories with 777 permission (as in dangerous)

Tags: directory, permissions, find, 777

I see some relevant discussions for using find to search and list all directory with 777 permissions.

```
find {root}/ -type d -perm 777 -exec find {} -name "*.php" \;
```

How would I modify this command, leaving out the php part?

Ooops. I found my answer: `ls -lR | grep ^d | grep "rwx "`

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting one `find` command with additional logic:

```
find / -type d -perm 777 -not -name "*.php" 2>/dev/null
```